# Comparing the first couple characters in a string

Tags: python, string, compare

So I have a list of strings:

```
list1 = ["1thing", "2thing", "3thing", "1thing"]
```

and I want to find out how many times each one is in the list. The thing is, I only want to compare the first couple of characters because I know that if the first, say 3 characters are the same, then the whole string is the same. I was thinking that I could modify the built in list.count(x) method, or I could override the `__eq__` operator but I'm not sure how to do either of those.

Comment: "I only want to compare the first couple of characters because I know that if the first, say 3 characters are the same, then the whole string is the same." Sounds like the sort of assumption that might break in the future. Why not just avoid the risk and just check the whole string? What do you gain from the extra complication and risk?

Comment: why even go through the whole hastle of trying to do the check at all when you can use in built collections.Counter module

Comment: I'm doing it because in reality, I'm checking a list that has more than 100,000 strings in it which are about 80 characters long and it might be faster to check the first 25 characters rather than all of them. I don't know if this is true, but I'm trying to test it out.

Comment: Have you done any benchmarks to show that using collections.Counter is not **fast enough**. The key is **fast enough**. If it is why go through the stress of optimizing. Beware of premature optimizations people say.

Comment: The built-in functions to compare strings are C code.  If you write custom Python code, will the Python code slow things down enough that just running the C code would be faster?  I don't know, but if you measure, you will know.  And I have to say, 100,000 strings really isn't that many, so even if it is faster to special-case them, you likely won't gain very much time.  I just ran a quick test: I generated 100,000 length-80 random strings, then counted them.  It took a fraction of a second to count them all, not doing any special tricks but just using the default string comparison.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a generator to extract the first couple of characters, and use the builtin `collections.Counter` class on that:

```
Counter(item[:2] for item in list1)
```

Answer (score 5):

why go through all the hastle..use the `collections.Counter` module to find frequencies.

```
>>> import collections
>>> x=['1thing', '2thing', '1thing', '3thing']
>>> y=collections.Counter(x)
>>> y
Counter({'1thing': 2, '2thing': 1, '3thing': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not as good as a solution as @Marcin's, but using `itertools.groupby` might make it more readable and flexible.

```
from itertools import groupby

def group_by_startswith(it, n):
    """Get a dict mapping the first n characters to the number of matches."""

    def first_n(str_):
        return str_[:n]

    startswith_sorted = sorted(it, key=first_n)
    groups = groupby(startswith_sorted, key=first_n)

    return {key: len(list(grouped)) for key, grouped in groups}
```

Example Output:

```
>>> list1 = ["1thing", "2thing", "3thing", "1thing"]
>>> print(group_by_startswith(list1, 3))
{'3th': 1, '2th': 1, '1th': 2}
```

This solution allows you a little more flexibility with the result.  For example, modifying the return line to return `grouped` or `list(grouped)` allows you to easily get the matching objects.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible to use an arbitrary key function as teh first element of a generator expression?

Comment: I guess I should have edited that a bit more.  I was trying to put a little unnecessary emphasis on using more functional tools (like `map`) when you're mapping a function over a series of values (IMO better when you have a more complicated mapping function).

Comment: generator expressions are just a syntax for mapping. It's more horses for courses, unless you need to optimise a hotspot.